# Is it possible to launch Jabref.exe from TeXstudio through user command?

Tags: texstudio, jabref

I try to call it from options> configure>build>..user command; with full path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JabRef.JabRef.exe"`, but this gave me this error:

```
Error: Could not start the command: C:\Program Files (x86)\JabRef.JabRef.exe.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  This question is entirely too vague.  What exactly did you try?  What error did you get?  What steps have you taken that haven't worked?  And so forth.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii, thanks for response. I just edited my question. Hope this will clarify

Comment: Why do you need to call JabRef?

Comment: @Werner, I just need JabRef to be opened while working on my thesis to see citation keys for my huge bib file and to push references. Beside I don`t know but I expect a lot from my favorite editor "Texstudio"..

Comment: @kosofo: Since you're using Windows, it's as easy as `Windows` + `S` > `jabref` > `Enter`.